# Bad Audio on Surface 3 with Xubuntu and linux-surface kernel

Tags: sound, soundcard, surface

I'm experiencing some bad audio issues on my Surface 3 device running Xubuntu with linux-surface kernel.
After the installation of the O.S. I found that I couldn't hear no sound. Issuing `alsamixer` I could see that the audio interface of the device was recognized (alsamixer allowed me to select the *sof-bytcht rt5645* audio interface), but when I selected it, I could see it had A LOT of settings which I really didn't know how to set and use. I post an extract of the settings to give an idea of the situation. The picture only shows the first page, but there are several more... Just make me know if you need me to share all of them.

[image: The fist page of the settings of the audio interface in alsamixer]

At first I just tried to unmute the speakers, but nothing happened. So I started unmuting and turning every element up just to see if I could get some sounds. I eventually managed to get some sound, but the sound was really awful... More specifically, it was full of noises and scratches like a disturbed radio station or similar... I also tried to plug my headphones into the device, but the sound was similarly bad...
I also found out that often, after a few tweaking of the controls, the device just shuts down unexpectedly.

Moreover, Surface's microphone seems not to be recognized and I just couldn't manage to capture anything at all. I also tried to plug in my headphones (which contain also a mic) and actually managed to hear something back... But, again, the audio was very very bad and after a while the device started to make really loud noises and strong whistles and I couldn't manage to make it stop (I just had to shut down the device)

I don't know if this is a problem with the drivers of if I have to tweak with the settings in alsamixer... In any case, could someone help me on this?

**Environment**

- *Hardware model:* Surface 3
- *Kernel version:* Linux ela-Surface-3 5.16.13-surface #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 11 01:08:37 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- *Distribution:* Xubuntu

Comment: Hello. What version of Xubuntu?

Comment: Hi @David, I used Xubuntu 20.04.4-desktop-amd64